# How to dismiss only last controller in stack without dismissing one by one

Tags: ios, uikit

For example we have uiviewcontrollers: vc0, vc1, vc2. Vc0 is root, vc1 added like presentViewController on vc0 and vc2 added like presentViewController on vc1. When I try call dismissViewController from vc0 animated, I want that only vc2 controller called method viewWillDisappear and only vc2 dismissed animated. But in real firstly dismissing vc2, BUT after that vc1 dismissing with calling methods viewDidAppear, viewDidDisappear and dismissing modally with animation as well. What should I do to dismiss all stack vc1 and vc2 at the same time animated?

Answer (score 0):

In `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` in vc1, you pass along the instance by doing

```
vc2.vc1 = self
```

and of course declaring `vc1` in Vc2.

Then, when you want to dismiss both, you do

```
self.dismiss(animated: true)
vc1.dismiss(animated: true)
```

Comment: I don't use storyboard and segue at all)

Comment: Yes you do. You stated that vc2 is added like `presentViewController` on vc1. This means you are performing a modal segue.